# Powershell script Select sort output by number

Tags: powershell, sorting

The following powershell script outputs a server diskspace report.

Is there a way of sorting the 'Percent' data in either desc or asc order?

[Script]

```ps
$computers | ForEach {
$Disks = Get-WMIObject Win32_Logicaldisk -ComputerName $_ -Filter "Drivetype=3" -Credential $cred -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
Select PSComputername, 
DeviceID, 
@{Name="Size GB";Expression={$_.Size/1GB -as [int]}},
@{Name="Used";Expression={ (($_.Size/1GB -as [int]) - ($_.Freespace/1GB -as [int])) }},
@{Name="Free";Expression={($_.Freespace/1GB -as [int])}},
@{Name="Percent";Expression={[math]::Round((($_.Freespace/1GB -as [int]) / ($_.Size/1GB -as [int]) ),2).toString("P") }}
$DiskSizeReport += $Disks
}
$DiskSizeReport | Select PSComputername, DeviceID, 'Size GB','Used','Free','Percent'
```

Output:

| PSComputerName | DeviceID | Size GB | Used | Free | Percent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Server 1 | E: | 1024 | 47 | 977 | 95,00% |
| Server 1 | F: | 500 | 131 | 369 | 74,00% |
| Server 1 | C: | 300 | 100 | 200 | 67,00% |

Answer (score 0):

Append to your command the following.

Ascending :

```
| Sort-Object -Property Percent
```

Descending :

```
| Sort-Object -Property Percent -Descending
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sort-Object` can also handle custom properties, so using that you need to convert the string values in column Percent into [double] numeric values in order to have the table sorted properly.

Seeing that in your case `ToString("P")` outputs percentages with a **comma** as decimal point, you need to change these into a dot too:

```
$DiskSizeReport | 
Sort-Object { [double]($_.Percent -replace '%' -replace ',', '.') } | 
Select PSComputername, DeviceID, 'Size GB','Used','Free','Percent'
```

Outputs

```
PSComputerName DeviceID Size GB Used Free Percent
-------------- -------- ------- ---- ---- -------
Server 1       C:       300     100  200  67,00% 
Server 1       F:       500     131  369  74,00% 
Server 1       E:       1024    47   977  95,00%
```